# Using mogrify - case insensitive file search

Tags: case-sensitivity, mogrify

I use mogrify as such:

`mogrify -monitor -quality 80 -resize 1200 *JPG`

However, this only matches files ending in .JPG. How do I include .jpg files at the same time (in other words, how to make the pattern case-insensitive)?

Comment: Yes it does! But not the accepted answer because that is about configuring it more permanently whereas I only want to use it once. This works it seems: *.[jJ][pP][gG] instead of .JPG. If you post it as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append the new filenames `mogrify -monitor -quality 80 -resize 1200 *.JPG *.jpg`. The wildcards are expanded by the shell before `mogrify` starts.

If you have the possibility of extensions like  `*.JpG`, filenames with spaces, etc, use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 |\
xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty mogrify -monitor  -quality 80 -resize 1200
```

Read `man find xargs`.